# AWS-Xray SDK is not getting disable in Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, devops, aws-xray

I have a XRAY_RECORDER dict in the setting.py file of Django. Where I have different settings for AWS Xrays like Daemon address, tracing name etc. In the same dict I also mentioned 'AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED': False. In short, I want to disable AWS Xray SDK for my application. But it still sends traces in spite of setting it to False.
Although I can turn it off using `global_sdk_config.set_sdk_enabled(False)` but due to requirements constraint, I have to enable or disable it via environment variables.
Can anyone please suggest a solution to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED setting is not supported in the django instrumentation of the SDK. Currently, for configuring the X-Ray recorder for a Django application, only [these](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/master/aws_xray_sdk/ext/django/conf.py#L25-L28) environment variables are supported within the settings.py file. You can set the environment variable AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED as False outside the application on your host if possible, to disable the SDK.